# unable to get the cross domain json response using script tag proxy

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am using a script tag proxy like this:

```
Ext.regModel('login',{fields:['status']});
var loginstore = new Ext.data.Store({ model:'login', proxy:{type:'scripttag',url:'myurl',reader:{type:'json',root:'data'}},autoLoad : true,});
loginstore.load();
```

In that, the url will return the response format below:

```
{"data":{"status":"error"}}
```

I am getting the error:

`unexpected token :`

Why am I getting this error? What are all the other ways to get the json response from cross domain without callback key and yql.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use scripttagproxy like that. Please have a look at [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?138533-quot-Uncaught-SyntaxError-Unexpected-token-quot-when-using-JSONP-and-scripttag) thread.

After you configure your server and callback function. You might want to try simpler method to call your cross-domain request as follows.

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: some_cross_domain_url,
    params: {param1: "something", param2: ...}
    callback:function(response){
    //response here will be JSON object.
    }
});
```

Please also have a look at [this](http://this) simple tutorial about how to configure your JSONP request.